# enable scroll inactive windows (for non windows 10) from c++ side

Tags: c++

I was digging quite some time now but without much luck. 
Is anyone aware about a method to enable Win10 feature "scroll inactive windows" for Win7/8 in some way in c++ for a specific program? I know there are some custom tools or registry hacks to enable this feature for these OS in general, but I didn't find a way yet to enable this somehow specifically for my program without having the user to mess with his OS.

A hint or link would be absolutely enough, I have no troubles reading some docs :)

Comment: It is a system setting with machine-wide side-effects.  Always turned on by default for Win10, not available for older versions.  So you can't do what you want to do, you'll have to make your program work either way.

Comment: Well, there are indeed ways to enable it- or at least "simulate" it to some degree on Win7 and Win8, but I still hope to find a way to get a similar effect coding wise.